# How can I make @XmlAttribute in a special order by using JAXB?

Tags: jaxb, xml-attribute

I have XML file which needs 3 attributes in an element. How can make the order of street, zip and city attribute as I wanted?

```xml
<address street="Big Street" zip="2012" city="Austin">
</address>
```

```java
@XmlType(name="Street)
@XmlRootElement(name = "Street")
public class Street {

@XmlAttribute
private String name;

@XmlAttribute
private String type;

    ... set and get method
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [@XmlAccessorOrder](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAccessorOrder.html)(has predefined values) or [@XmlType](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlType.html)(Only works for properties) to govern the ordering.

[Samples](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19355-01/819-3669/bnbcz/index.html)

Edit :

For custom ordering JAXB specification doesnt provide anything, but you can do if your JAXB provider provides you some features.

Found this [link](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=975397) where it speaks about ordering using EclipseLink JAXB.

Comment: yeah, it seems like we can do nothing on it.

Comment: Yeah unless you restore to provider APIs

Answer (score 10):

Anecdotally, the attributes seem to be in reverse order than they are mentioned in code.  In my case, I'm using two variables (name & value) and I had to declare them as:

```
// The inverse order of name & value seems to make them render in XML in name/value order
@XmlAttribute
protected String value;
@XmlAttribute
protected String name;
```

When the XML is generated, it results in the following:

```
<attribute name="nameValue" value="valueValue"/>
```

Comment: It seems they are sorted alphabetically in Java 6 and in the order of declaration on Java 7 (in both cases using the built-in JDK JAXB provider).

Comment: Java 7 also seems to take `propOrder` into account.